# Too many App Engine instances running after HRD migration

Tags: google-app-engine

I migrated an old master/slave App Engine app to HRD last week. Since the migration, it has been running out of Frontend Instance Hours quota every day. It wasn't running out of quota before migration. What changed?

Looking at the dashboard, I don't see a traffic spike that would be causing this. However, I do see that it is running 4 instances even though there's almost no traffic. Before the migration, it almost never ran more than 1 instance:

[image: 4 instances running, but no traffic]

Why is it running more instances after the migration? How can I troubleshoot this?

(I went looking for the performance sliders for controlling how many instances it prefers to start, but I couldn't find them)

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, the performance sliders have been removed. This is controlled through module [settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration) now, particularly `max_idle_instances`.

In the dashboard, click on the pulldown menu that is set to *Summary* in your picture and pick *Instances*. If you have more than 1 instance that's billed throughout the day, this explains why you're running out of quota. Just set `max_idle_instances` to 1. App Engine may still keep more than 1 idle instance, but you won't be billed for it.

This can obviously have an adverse effect on performance during peak traffic, because the scheduler may have to spin up an instance before serving a request. Your traffic seems low enough to not be affected.

Comment: oh, so even though I'm not using modules in my app (it is a very small app) the scaling options for modules apply?

Comment: Also, when I try to set max_idle_instances, I get this error: The Modules feature is not available to applications using the specified runtime: python. I assume that means I also have to upgrade to python2.7?